# Washsale for daytrading

Tags: united-states, taxes, day-trading, wash-sale

I have following scenario of washsale ? Can someone please help me if wash sale will apply to me in any case ? 
I knwo for three trades i made in Dec 2019 has wash sale but is covered with profit I made oon 12/16/19. So basically i had net profit in 2019. However I am not sure of what to do for the loss I made on 01/16/2020.

TGT traded on 12/17/19 with a loss of $7.5 ( qty 250)

TGT traded on 12/20/19 with a loss of $26 ( qty 200)

TGT traded on 12/26/19 with a PROFIT of $98 ( qty 200)

in year 2020 ---

TGT traded on 01/16/2020 with loss of $23.90 ( qty 150)

** All of these are day trades ( bought and sold same day). **

Comment: You need to specify if these "trades" are buys or sells. IF they are all sells then there is no wash sale (provide that there were no buys in the 30 days before or after)

Comment: "Traded" means what?  If you owned 800 shares of TGT and sold those shares off in 4 trades on different dates, there are no wash sales.  If you bought replacement shares within 30 days before or after realizing a loss, you have a wash sale situation.

Comment: @Prakash   My guess is that on each of the three days you trade TGT you both bought the stock and then sold the stock. Do I have that right?

Comment: @Bob , Yes  all of these were intraday trades ( so bought and sold same day ) . Sorry i forgot to mention.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming I understand your situation correctly, some of these trades are indeed wash sale violations. However this is not quite as bad as it seems as the wash sale rules (assuming these trades were all in your taxable brokerage account) do not prevent you from claiming the loss, they merely roll it over into your next holding of the same asset.

From what I can tell, in your situation the first trade was a wash, meaning the basis of 200 of these shares is rolled into the second trade, therefore you have 50 shares with a loss of $0.03 each and 200 shares with a loss of $0.16 each.

When you buy the third lot the wash loss of the second lot will roll into it, giving you an effective gain of $0.33 per share.

Thus in 2019 you have a gain of $0.33 on 200 shares and a loss $0.03 on 50 shares. These should both be realised.

Finally the trade in 2020 is at least 30 days from 12/17/19 so should not be a wash, so that loss will be realised assuming you do not buy again within 30 days.

Your broker however should normally list all this on your 1099 assuming you use a single account so you should not usually have to calculate this manually.

Comment: Excellent details. This is very useful. So easy to understand after your explanation. Thankyou so much for that. Yes, all of these transactions were in same borkerage account.